# Angular error is not displayed with custom validator

Tags: angular, angular-validation

here is my custom validator:

```
form = new FormGroup({
    temperatureMid: new FormControl(0, [
      this.secondLimitGreaterFirst(),
      Validators.required
    ])
  });

secondLimitGreaterFirst(): ValidatorFn {
    return (): {[key: string]: boolean} => {
      if (1 === 1) { // only for testing
        return { greater: true };
      } else {
        return { greater: false };
      }
      };
    }
```

and now I want to show an error to the user for this custom validator but I dont know how.

```
<mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput type="number" placeholder="{{ 'device.configure.temperaturePlaceholderMid' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="data.tempMid" formControlName="temperatureMid"> 
                  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('temperatureMid').hasError('secondLimitGreaterFirst')">Zweiter Wert muss größer sein</mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('temperatureMid').hasError('required')">{{ 'input.errors.required' | translate }}</mat-error> 
                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Should be `form.get('temperatureMid').hasError('greater')`

Comment: Also, if there is no error return `null`, not an object.

Comment: For more context on @BojanKogoj helpful comment see the Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-reactive-forms.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error, return `null`:

```js
form = new FormGroup({
    temperatureMid: new FormControl(0, [
      this.secondLimitGreaterFirst(),
      Validators.required
    ])
  });

secondLimitGreaterFirst(): ValidatorFn {
    return (): {[key: string]: boolean} => {
      if (1 === 1) { // only for testing
        return { greater: true };
      } else {
        return null; // <<<<--------- here return null if no error
      }
   };
}
```

Then use it in the html by using greater attribute as you used in the returned object :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" placeholder="{{ 'device.configure.temperaturePlaceholderMid' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="data.tempMid" formControlName="temperatureMid"> 
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('temperatureMid').hasError('greater')">Zweiter Wert muss größer sein</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('temperatureMid').hasError('required')">{{ 'input.errors.required' | translate }}</mat-error> 
</mat-form-field>
```